# Java Color encode RGB into single integer?

Tags: java, colors, bit-manipulation, rgb

I'm reading "Java The Complete Reference Ninth Edition" and the writer gives this example of creating a Color object out a single integer that encodes the RGB values he says :

> The integer is organized with red in bits 16 to 23, green in bits
>   8 to 15, and blue in bits 0 to 7. Here is an example of this constructor:

```
int newRed = (0xff000000 | (0xc0 << 16) | (0x00 << 8) | 0x00);
Color darkRed = new Color(newRed);

0xff000000 in hexadecimal is equivalent to  0b11111111000000000000000000000000 in binary
```

which's a 32 bit integer...
I understand bit-wise manipulation but what I don't understand is :

What's the use of the ones in the start of the number? why doesn't start with zeros

Comment: I'm always curious with what's wrong with [`Color#getRGB`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB--) and [`Color(int, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color-int-boolean-) ... but I might be missing something :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Javadocs for `Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) explain that the Java `Color` class contains an alpha channel as well as RGB--so a color that started with all zeroes would be completely transparent. The color represented by `0xff000000` is *opaque* black.

In this case, of course, the author has made an error. The single-argument constructor ignores the high byte. Instead, it should have used `new Color(0xffc00000, true)` if he wanted to specify the alpha (or, more simply, `new Color(0xc0, 0, 0, 0xff)`).

Comment: Thank u for ur answer, it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to ask why 0xff000000 was added to the party.
It is really implementation dependent.
My guess is one of two options:
1. Color does nothing with those bits and just to be on the safe side, you set the irrelevant bits to 1 (so overflowing the reds won't be any different than not).
2. That is the alpha channel (This makes more sense than the former)

edit:
Now I realize you were talking about the awt Color object, so the corrent answer is option no. 2.